# Possible too long JVM pause

Tags: ignite

I'm using single server Ignite.NET configuration. And after a various working time of the server, it crashes and the following message appears:

```
Possible too long JVM pause
```

But I doubt that the issue is related to JVM garbage collection, because I found one regularity:
This message is always preceded by the following:

```
[WARNING][sys-stripe-11-#12][Marshaller] Type 'System.ArgumentException' implements 'System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable'. It will be written in Ignite binary format, however, the following limitations apply: DateTime fields would not work in SQL; sbyte, ushort, uint, ulong fields would not work in DML.
```

I don't think it's a coincidence. But I don't store in Ignite any ArgumentException instances, so I don't understand how ArgumentException is related to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The warning likely happens at the beginning of data load operation, while JVM pause may be caused by the bulk data loading.

It does seem that you have an exception stored somewhere.

Comment: Sometimes the pause is about 5 minutes, but it does not seem that server hangs. I don't store any exception objects in Ignite. I think that some exception is thrown in my code, but Ignite catches it and tries to serialize it for some reason and prints this warning. So now I try to catch it and if I will reach success my assumption will be confirmed